# How to change body style using angular

Tags: javascript, angularjs, jqlite

I have the following code and a bunch of other angular code :-

```
<body class="ftb2">

a lot of code here
</body>
```

and in the angular controller i have

```
var bodyTemp = $document[0].body;
                bodyTemp.removeClass("ftb2");
```

it gets the bodytemp but does not remove the class.
From the chrome debugger :-

```
bodyTemp: body.ftb2
aLink: ""
```

etc....

Not sure what is the reason?

PS:- My angualar scope is defined inside a div within the body and i cannot change that so my code is like :-

```
<body class="ftb2">
<!-- angular boot strapped with this id-->
<div id="xyz">
</div>
</body>
```

bootstrap code :-

```
var root = document.getElementById("xyz");

 angular.bootstrap(root, ["appInvest"])
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Its bad way of doing this, since there is no option to do it you need to add some DOM manipulation from controller.

```
angular.element($document).find('body').removeClass('ftb2')
```

[**Working Plunkr**](http://plnkr.co/edit/9T3MPBkmNvxjGJWYvWTn?p=preview)

Comment: I have edited the question with other details, my angualr scope is defined withing the body in a div.